# Question on GSpin-valued L-parameters

Tags: representation-theory, galois-representations

Let $\Gamma$ be a topological group, $n \geq 1$ an integer, $\ell$ a prime number, and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$ the algebraic closure of the $\ell$-adic integers.  We set $\Phi(GSpin_{2n + 1})$ to be the set of continuous maps $\phi: \Gamma \rightarrow GSpin_{2n + 1}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$ valued in the general spin group up to $GSpin_{2n + 1}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$-conjugacy and $\Phi(GL_{2^{n}})$ to be the set of continuous maps $\phi: \Gamma \rightarrow GL_{2^{n}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$ up to $GL_{2^{n}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$-conjugacy. We have the spin representation relating the two objects
\begin{equation}
spin: GSpin_{2n + 1} \rightarrow GL_{2^{n}} 
\end{equation}
This defines a map
\begin{equation}
 \Phi(GSpin_{2n + 1}) \rightarrow \Phi(GL_{2^{n}}) 
\end{equation}
The question then is how can one describe the fibers of this map? For example, for $n = 2$, then we have the exceptional isomorphism $GSpin_{5} \simeq GSp_{4}$ and the spin representation is simply the embedding
\begin{equation}
 std: GSp_{4} \hookrightarrow GL_{4} 
\end{equation}
From this, it easy to see the fibers of the map over a parameter $\phi: \Gamma \rightarrow GL_{4}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$ are determined by the similitude character
\begin{equation}
 sim(\phi): \Gamma \xrightarrow{\phi} GL_{2^{n}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}) \xrightarrow{det} \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}^{*}
\end{equation}

What can one say in general?

Comment: You should ask this on MathOverflow. A good place to start could be [this paper of Kret-Shin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04223.pdf): the goal is to show that the Galois representation attached to an aut rep of $\mathrm{GSp}_{2n}$ is valued in $\mathrm{GSpin}_{2n+1}$. But the folks over at Mathoverflow can probably give you a more precise reference.

Comment: By the way, in the $n = 2$ case, the similitude isn't as you described: you should have $\mathrm{sim}^2 = \det$. Also, I think the standard representation of $\mathrm{GSp}_4$ is the one that's valued in $\mathrm{SO}_5\subset\mathrm{GL}_5$.

Comment: Ya. You are right. Sorry I shouldn't have written determinant of course! I have looked at that paper of Kret-Shin, but I don't think they say anything about this question beyond the case of n = 2. In the appendix, they do explain this fact about it being characterized by the similitude character! I didn't mean standard representation, rather the "standard embedding" but you are right I should have been more clear.